# Update Case-Sensitive DB Field In Laravel 5.3 With Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update a database column field with raw SQL in laravel. It's important to mention that the update code was written to MySQL drive but now I use Postgres. The column name is `dayID`. So the update code is:

```
DB::update("update table set travel = ... WHERE dayID = {$this->dayID}");
```

I must use raw SQL because I make some updates to polygon types.

The problem is that laravel automatically transforms the `dayID` to `dayid` so I get an error:

```
column "dayid" does not exist
```

I tried to set a variable in order to use it in update query but it also failed with the same error:

```
$var = "dayID";
DB::update("update table set travel = ... WHERE ".$var." = {$this->dayID}");
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try DB::table with update below:

```
DB::table('table_name')
        ->where('dayID', $this->dayID)
        ->update(['travel' => '...']);
```

Laravel document :

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#updates